# Using grep to find all occurrences of the following pattern

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find all occurrences of pattern that looks like this:

```
/*  93 */
/*  94 */
/*     */
/*  96 */
/*  99 */
/*     */
/* 101 */
```

I've failed miserably producing the correct regex. Desired goal would be to find all that match all the above

Expressions I've treid

```
(\/)(\*)(\s)(\s)(\d)(\d)(\s)(\*)(\/)
```

It matches the first occurance of `/*  somenumber */` but no subsequent matches. It also wont match times when there are three digit numbers and also ones with no numbers

Comment: @RicardoLohmann This is what I've tried to \/(\*)\d\/(\*)

Comment: Please go back and put the actual code in the question.  Then, tell us what isn't working, such as "It matches this and this, but not these."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

`\/\*[^\*]*\*\/`

http://www.rubular.com/r/HMDl9QH3uq

Comment: wow, wizard. that is what I was after! thanks. (good site too double thanks)

Comment: I understand the other parts of the expression but can you verbally iterate this expression [^\\\*]* by chance (its apart of the answer you supplied)

Comment: @stackoverflow `[...]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). `^` marks it as a "negated character classes" matching any character that is *not* inside the class. `\\` is a literal backslash. `*` is just a literal asterisk when inside a character class. And then the `*` after the character class repeats it 0 or more times. Hence this matches `/*`, then as many non-slash, non-asterisk characters as possible, then `*/`. Note that this does not allow for asterisks and slashes inside the comment.

Comment: @stackoverflow Sure, when you use ` [^] ` you will match everything except what's after the `^`, so ` [^\\*] ` matches everything except ` \ ` and ` * `. It can be simplified to ` [^\*] `.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for

```
 \/\*\s*\d+\s*\*\/
```

---

No need of grouping each and every part in `regex` unless you want to store it in a group

`\d+` matches 1 to many digits..

`\s*` matches 0 to many spaces..

Comment: Thank you I appreciate the response and clarification

Answer (score 0):

Try   `/\* *[0-9 ][0-9 ][0-9 ] *\*/`

This expression will select just your rows and will not select

```
/* xxx */

/* c */

/* 1014 */
```